# Is there an algorithm to check that a subgroup of a CAT$(0)$ group is *not* quasiconvex?

Tags: group-theory, algorithms, finitely-generated, geometric-group-theory, coxeter-groups

Let $G$ be a finitely generated CAT$(0)$ group and $H$ a subgroup. If $H$ is quasiconvex then it is finitely generated, so we can immediately conclude that any non-finitely generated subgroup of $G$ is not quasiconvex. Let us assume then that $H$ is finitely generated, and suppose $H$ is given as a finite set of generators $X\subset G$.

**Question:** Is there an algorithm which takes as input the group $G$ (in some suitable format) and the set $X$ and outputs whether $H=\langle X\rangle$ is *not* quasiconvex?

I am specifically interested in the case of a right-angled Coxeter system $(W,S)$ which is CAT$(0)$ as seen by making it act on their Davis complex - a CAT$(0)$ cube complex. In [1], Pallavi Dani and Ivan Levcovitz give a procedure (*standard completion sequence*) which takes in a finite set $X\subset W$ and which terminates after finitely many steps if and only if $\langle X\rangle$ is quasiconvex, see Theorem 8.4. I want to know if there is an algorithm, ie a procedure which terminates after finitely many steps, which tells me that a subgroup is *not* quasiconvex.

I have searched on MSE and MO, as well as Googling the literature on the subject but found nothing. I know there are certain invariants which can help prove in certain cases that a subgroup is not quasiconvex (eg growth rate), but this does not amount to a generally applicable algorithm.

I have asked the question in the very general setting of CAT$(0)$ groups, but would be happy with an algorithm which works in a restricted setting, eg CAT$(-1)$ groups; groups which act on a CAT$(0)$ cube complex (compare Theorem 8.4 mentioned above with Theorem 5.1 in [2]); right-angled Coxeter groups, etc.

If it turns out that this problem is undecidable, that would also be interesting.

[1] Pallavi Dani and Ivan Levcovitz *[Subgroups of right-angled Coxeter groups via Stallings-like techniques](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.09046.pdf)*, 2021.

[2] Michael Ben-Zvi, Robert Kropholler, and Rylee Alanza Lyman *[Folding-like techniques for CAT$(0)$ cube complexes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2011.05374.pdf)*, 2020.

**Edit:** The definition of *quasiconvex subgroup* I am using is as follows: a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is $M$-quasiconvex, for $M \ge 0$, if any geodesic path in the Cayley graph of $G$ with endpoints in $H$ lies in the $M$-neighborhood of $H$. $H$ is quasiconvex if it is $M$-quasiconvex for some $M$. Whether or not a subgroup is quasiconvex does not depend on which finite generating set of $G$ is used to construct the Cayley graph.

Comment: Are you aware of the Rips construction?

Comment: Heard of, but never studied it. If you can give me an answer in terms of this construction I'd be happy to go away and study it as necessary

Comment: Well, it is directly relevant for your question. Incidentally, what is your definition of qc subgroups in the CAT(0) setting?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Even a sketch of how it is relevant would be helpful. I have added in my definition of quasiconvexity. This is the one taken from [1] so might be suited to a more specific setting than arbitrary CAT$(0)$ groups, but should be good enough for RACGs at least. Apologies if this is the case.

Comment: The answer  is no for hyperbolic groups. It was proved by Bridson and Wise that quasiconvexity is undecidable for finitely generated subgroups of hyperbolic groups. On the other hand, this property can be verified. It follows that there can be no algorithm to verify non-quasiconvexity.

Comment: Amazing, thank you @DerekHolt